# What is the use of the save/publish/validate/stop events?

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I'm new to marketing cloud development and I have to say that I'm having a hard time to get my head around the logic that I should implement in order to properly build a Custom Activity component.

I've read the developer documentation and also some sample code that I found on github but it's still not clear to me what should I do in each event handler on my REST backend, in particular regarding with the save/publish/stop/validate events.

If my understanding is correct those events will be triggered by Journey Builder when the respective action happens while I'm editing my Journey in Journey Builder. Ie, when I save the Journey the save event will be fired and sent to my REST "save" endpoint handler.

But what exactly should I do in each handler? What are they're practical use?

The majority of code I found so far only handles any logic in the execute event handler, so what is the point for those save/validate/publish and stop events?

For example, if I'm writing a Custom Activity to send SMS messages where the UI has a textarea for the user to write an SMS message template, am I supposed to save this message when the user saves the journey and recover it during execution to actually render the message and send it? And if that is the case, in which event handler should I recover the message template to allow the user to edit and update it?

Also why there is no delete event handler to inform me that the Journey has been deleted?

Finally can anyone point me some good book, article or courses regarding developing custom activities? The SF documentation seems really scarse and target for developers who are alreadt trained in this kind of development.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The logc that executes when those routes are called is going to depend on your application, and use-case, but they must return some response to JB. Let's say you wanted to log an event every time someone edited/saved a version of the activity so that you could provide monitoring for errant configurations, that would be a scenario where you'd want to execute some logic when those routes are being used. If you want to bypass running any logic in these scenarios, just return a 200 response.

In regards to allowing your users to configure an instance of an activity, and having that configuration persist when a user accesses the instance, you'll need to setup functions in your client-side controller that call the `initActivity` and `updateActivity` Postmonger events. Using the former, you're able to declare a function that can access the already configured payload (or check that it is NULL) while the latter is executed when a user saves a given instance configuration. For reference, here is a simple example:

```
connection.on("initActivity", initialize);

function initialize(data) {
  // Check if payload is NULL, else set configured value for UI input
  if (data) {
    payload = data;
    var setobjectID = payload["arguments"].execute.inArguments[0].objectID;
    $("#objectID").val(setobjectID);
  }
}

function save() {
  var objectID = $("#objectID").val();
  payload["arguments"].execute.inArguments = [{
    tokens: authTokens,
    subscriberKey: "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + '."SubscriberKey"}}',
    objectID: objectID
  }, ];
  payload["metaData"].isConfigured = true;
  connection.trigger("updateActivity", payload);
}
```

For your question on why there is no delete handler setup, there would be no event for JB to broadcast because the interaction would be deleted. If you somehow did need to determine this, you could easily setup logging in your app configuration or make requests periodically w/ a microservice to provide automated notifications.

In regards to helpful courses/articles, I'm not sure you're going to find much more depth than what exists in the standard docs and on github repos. I'd recommend becoming more familiar with the Postmonger events reference as well as any languages/frameworks that you are using to build your application. Most of the work involved in creating this will be fairly agnostic to Marketing Cloud outside of the initial configuration and events broadcast.

Comment: Hi jason, thanks for the explanations. I don't have enough points to vote it as correct, but thanks!